# c# SmartDevice Cab Installer with .net runtime installer included

Tags: c#, .net, cab, smart-device

I need to be able to create an install in vs2008 that will install my app and setup .net cf on the smartdevice, because my app requires it.

Is this possible.  If so, how can be it be accomplished.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for 2005, should be almost the same.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446504.aspx